# AT28C16 Interface Help

Tags: eeprom, bus, addressing

I pulled an AT28C16 from an old KVM switch and have managed to wire it up like so:

- A0-10 -> GND
- CE -> GND
- WE -> 5V
- OE -> GND
- VCC -> 5V
- GND -> GND
- I/O0-7 -> Floating. Plugged by hand to level meter one by one.

With all of the address bus lines hooked to GND, I am able to read the first 8 bits as 01110000. This is all well and good, however [the datasheet](http://cva.stanford.edu/classes/cs99s/datasheets/at28c16.pdf) says this is a 16K EEPROM, and this chip has 11 Address Bus line, which equates to 2048 combinations and therefore 2048 bytes or 2048*8 bits. Thats not 16,000 bytes. How to I read the full 16K with only 11 Address Bus lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unit K in computer means 1024 bits. So 16K is 16*1024 or 16384 bits. The datasheet says,

> The AT28C16 is a 16K memory
>   organized as 2,048 words by 8 bits.

And since it has got 2^11 (or 2K) address lines, each of which will point to one of these words.

You can determine which word you want to write data in or read from by setting appropriate bits in A0-A10.

Comment: So this totals in simplistic terms 2048 Bytes of 8 bit length, with Bytes simply being given the fancy name "Words"?

Comment: Yes, note that a word is a fixed-sized piece of data. Here it has the size of 8 bits or 1 byte. It can have larger sizes depending on the processor.

Comment: I respectfully disagree that "*The unit K in computer means 1024 bits*". As explained in another answer, yes it used to definitely mean 1024 (although that can't be assumed now) but not necessarily *bits*. Many times if someone says "16k of memory" without specifying the units, they could be referring to *bytes* or *words* - it all depends on the context, is ambiguous, and this is exactly why the OP of this question was confused. So although in *this* Atmel datasheet, it says "16K" and means *bits*, when "k" is said on its own, it doesn't *necessarily* refer to the number of *bits* - all IMHO.

Comment: It could point out that in the old days we all used to take the SI **k** (kilo) prefix and cheerfully use it as meaning 1000 or 1024 upon the context, infact leaving the thing up to personal interpretation.

This has been disambigued introducing **Ki** prefix which means 1024 and this is what (since 1990something) has to be used for _computer stuff_ , retaining **k** for _normal_ 1000 prefix.

Of course old datasheets, and sadly many new as well, do not comply.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte

Answer (score 2):

AT28C16 is a 16-kilobit EEPROM, not a 16-kilobyte one.